# Is it worth reducing my poly count?

Tags: rendering, materials, normals, topology, baking

*(Disclaimer: Although I've worked with Blender on and off for a few years now, I consider myself a novice in many areas, as this is just a hobby for me)*

So I'm currently creating a library scene, and before you ask, yes, the books and bookshelves have been made together and turned into low poly models, however I have a number of models that I've had a significant amount of trouble in reducing the poly count.

I was thinking about using these models in a game, so I know the importance of actually reducing the poly count, but it's just not working out as planned. I was almost considering giving up on the game aspect until I read that some models in games have 10k poly counts (which is very achievable for my models)

So my question is now, how many is "too many"? 
an additional point of information is that lighting & texturing is all baked to the models, there isn't a great deal of dynamic lighting even in the game - so would this allow me to get away with higher poly models??

Comment: what engine are we talking about and what device do you plan to port your game on?

Comment: I was going to make it on Unity or Unreal (as they are free) and for PC

Comment: Then if you keep it under 300k vertices per frame you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks, where did you get that benchmark? and are there ways I can increase that further?

Comment: It's a rough lower estimate what I think would run smoothly at 60fps even on an old hardware or integrated gpu. For better estimates I suggest look in Unity or Unreal forums or best benchmark your scenes, as the framerate depends on other million things.